# Error displaying map in Android application using maps application

Tags: android, maps

I am building a Xamarin Android app to display map.  I do not want to use Google Maps so I am trying the Maps application that is in-built.  Please see the code below to create the intent and invoke it using StartActivity:

```
   var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("geo:42.374260,-71.120824");

   var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView,        Android.Net.Uri.Parse("geo:42.374260,-71.120824"));

   StartActivity(mapIntent);
```

I get error on the StartActivity statement that ActivityNotFoundException.  If I change the Uri to any regular webaddress (http://www.google.com) then the app displays that website.  So I believe the problem is parsing the geo address.

I have included following references:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Net;
```

Please let me know what am I missing .

Thanks !